# ¿Cómo usar las estructuras anidadas con punteros C?

Tags: c, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos, punteros

Tengo esta estructura principal

```
struct materias
{
    char nombre[30];
    char profesor[30];
    char tipoDeMateria[20];
    char horasSemanales[10];
    struct actividades *actividad;
    struct fechasEspeciales *fechas;
    struct materias *siguiente;
};
```

y esta otra estructura

```
struct fechasEspeciales
{
    char tipo[30];
    int dia;
    int mes;
    char horaDeIncio[8];
    char horaDeFin[8];
    struct fechasEspeciales *siguiente;
};
```

¿Cómo hago para hacer el llamado a la segunda estructura para que quede registrado cada fecha especial por materia?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Te refieres a que cada `materias` debe almacenar un nº indeterminado de `fechasEspeciales` y quieres saber cómo añadir `fechasEspeciales` dentro de `materias`?

Comment: Exacto porque yo puse (registroNuevo->fechas->tipo, tipo) el segundo tipo es la variable que le estoy pasando, compila todo bien pero cuando le ejecutó y llega a esa parte recibe todas las variables luego sale segmentation fault (core dumped) y de queda hasta ahí

Comment: Me cuesta mucho entender a qué te refieres, ¿puedes poner el USO que le das a las estructuras para determinar cuál es exáctamente el problema que tienes?

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que una materia puede almacenar una lista de fechas.

Ignoro las funciones que has implementado para gestionar las estructuras. A mi se me ocurre esta opción pero eso no quiere decir que sea la única:

```
// Esta función añade un nuevo elemento a la lista
// Si la lista está vacía (puntero nulo), el nuevo elemento pasa a ser el primero de la lista
// El nuevo elemento será accesible via el puntero doble nuevoElemento
struct fechasEspeciales* NuevoElemento(
  struct fechasEspeciales* inicioLista,
  struct fechasEspeciales** nuevoElemento)
{
  *nuevoElemento = (struct fechasEspeciales*)calloc(1,sizeof(struct fechasEspeciales));

  if( inicioLista == 0 )
  {
    inicioLista = *nuevoElemento;
  }
  else
  {
    struct fechasEspeciales* ptr = inicioLista;
    while( ptr->siguiente )
      ptr = ptr->siguiente;

    ptr->siguiente = *nuevoElemento;
  }

  return inicioLista;
}

struct materias materia;
materias.fecha = 0; // inicialización

// Añadir 3 fechas
for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
{
  struct fechasEspeciales* nuevaFecha;
  materia.fechas = NuevoElemento(materias.fecha,&nuevaFecha);
  nuevaFecha->dia = 10+i; // Para simular el cambio de dia
  nuevaFecha->mes = 11;
// ...
}
```

Después del bucle, en `materia.fechas` encontrarás una lista con tres elementos, lo que podemos comprobar con una función para imprimir la lista:

```
void ImprimirFechas(struct fechasEspeciales* lista)
{
  while( lista )
  {
    printf("Fecha: %d/%d\n",lista->dia,lista->mes);
    lista = lista->siguiente;
  }
}

ImprimirFechas(materia.fechas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo de tu pregunta, lo que necesitas saber especificamente es como acceder a los campos de una estructura que se encuentra dentro de otra.

En una estructura convencional se utiliza el operador `.` supongamos el siguiente ejemplo:

```
struct materias
{
    char nombre[30];
    char profesor[30];
    char tipoDeMateria[20];
    char horasSemanales[10];
};
```

Para escribir el campo  `nombre` podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
struct materias mi_variable;
strcpy(mi_variable.nombre,"ilfredo"); // Porque nombre es un char* y no puedes escribirlo como una variable convencional
```

Ahora utilicemos la misma estructura, pero accediendola con un puntero en lugar de hacerlo por valor:

```
struct materias
{
    char nombre[30];
    char profesor[30];
    char tipoDeMateria[20];
    char horasSemanales[10];
};
```

Para escribir el campo  `nombre` podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
struct materias * mi_puntero;
strcpy(mi_puntero->nombre,"ilfredo");
```

El operador `->` se utiliza cuando trabajas con un puntero a una estructura. Es completamente equivalente a utilizar los operadores `*`y `.` a la vez. Esto se debe a que primero deberías utilizar `*` para desreferenciar la estructura y luego `.` para acceder al campo que te interesa en particular

Ahora supongamos el siguiente ejemplo:

```
struct materias
{
    char nombre[30];
    char profesor[30];
    char tipoDeMateria[20];
    char horasSemanales[10];
    struct fechasEspeciales fechas; // Modifiqué esta estructura para que se entienda mejor la explicacion (Eliminé el puntero)
};

struct fechasEspeciales
{
    char tipo[30];
    int dia;
    int mes;
    char horaDeIncio[8];
    char horaDeFin[8];
    struct fechasEspeciales *siguiente;
};
```

En este caso para escribir el campo `dia`deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
struct materias mi_variable;
mi_variable.fechas.dia=24; // Para escribir una estructura dentro de otra, se usa el operador `.` una vez por cada estructura.
```

Y ahora si llegamos al caso que planteaste que une todos los ejemplos anteriores en un solo caso:

```
struct materias
{
    char nombre[30];
    char profesor[30];
    char tipoDeMateria[20];
    char horasSemanales[10];
    struct actividades *actividad;
    struct fechasEspeciales *fechas;
    struct materias *siguiente;
};

struct fechasEspeciales
{
    char tipo[30];
    int dia;
    int mes;
    char horaDeIncio[8];
    char horaDeFin[8];
    struct fechasEspeciales *siguiente;
};
```

Ahora no tienes una estructura dentro de otra, sino que tienes una estructura que contiene un puntero a otra estructura, y para escribir el campo `dia` deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
 struct materias mi_variable;
 (mi_variable.fechas)->dia=24;
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda, saludos!

Comment: Use como me dijiste el (registroNuevo.fechas)->dias = 24; pero me da error ya que fechas es un apuntador

Comment: Justamente como fechas es un puntero, no deberías tener problema utilizando el operador `->`, estas seguro que lo estas utilizando en forma correcta? Te sugiero postear el bloque de código que estas usando

Comment: Me dice que el error está es en el '.' no en la '->',(registroNuevo.fechas)->tipo el error lo da dentro del paréntesis donde está el '.'

Comment: Entonces seguramente sea porque registroNuevo no es una estructura como dijiste, sino que es un puntero a una estructura. En ese caso tendrás que usar (registroNuevo->fechas)->día